# Demystify the Hilbert Function

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, hilbert-polynomial

Let $I \subseteq k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ be an ideal for a field $k$ and let $A = k[x_1,\dots,x_n]/I$. For $d \geq 0$ let 
$$ A_{\le d} := \{f + I : f \in k[x_1,\dots,x_n], \deg{f} \leq d \}.$$
The *Hilbert function* of $I$ is
$$ h_I: \mathbb{N}_0 \to \mathbb{N}_0, \ h_I(d) = \dim_k(A_{\leq d}). $$

This object seems quite random (at least to me) at first but after some "magic" happens, it somehow turns out to have great properties. For instance, it's a polynomial $p_I$ for all sufficiently large $d$ and we get $\deg(p_I) = \dim(A)$.

This begs the question: Why? Why should we have expected $h_I$ to be nice? How did people (probably Hilbert?) conjecture these things?

Comment: Isn't $I$ supposed to be homogeneous?

Comment: No. At least not in our lecture.

Comment: Maybe this is why you are looking for a "demystification". Usually the Hilbert function and its generating series, that is, the Hilbert series, are defined for graded $k$-algebras. In that case, $h_R(d):=\dim_kR_d$, and if one starts with the Artinian case ($\dim R=0$) can notice that a polynomial occurs.

Comment: Hmm, weird. We‘re currently dealing with the graded case but are still taking the definition I wrote. So that‘s interesting, thank you! Sorry, if it‘s trivial, though, but I don‘t quite see why the graded case “demystifies“ the Hilbert function. Could you elaborate a bit more on that, please?

Comment: I think that [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2263954/ideal-associated-to-a-set-of-points-of-mathbbpn-in-general-position/2692574#2692574) can be useful.